# How do I control my "location" in a Word 2003 file using VBA macro?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a somewhat random issue with some Visual Basic macros (6.3) in Word 2003, that after the macro executes, I'm not "where I'm supposed to be". I don't know the relevant technical terms, which makes it hard to look up relevant information: I'm asking what the applicable technical concept is. When I have more than one Word file open and run certain search-and-replace macros, at the end of execution the window on top looks correct, but I cannot then type or click in that file, because Word thinks that I'm in a different file, so I have to tab to that different file, click, then tab back to the desired file. In addition, in the "switched-to" file, I am often sent to the top of the file so I have to manually recover my original position. Since this is a random problem, it is really hard to debug and eliminate the underlying cause. It appears (non-systematic investigation) that Word sends me to the first file in the ring of open Word files.

Presumably there is something addressable in Word corresponding to "this is the file (in the ring of open files) that I'm currently in" and "this is where I am in that file", which could be saved and restored. All I can find is information on getting the file path. As you can see from my archaic use of the word "ring", I don't even know what term described the relation between a set of files open in Word. What technical terms should I be looking for? It would also be helpful if you could suggest code for how to "save" and "restore" the file.

Here is one example of a macro that has had that problem:

```
Sub Lengthen()
'
' Lengthen Macro
'
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "([aeiou" & ChrW(618) & ChrW(650) & "]):"
        .Replacement.Text = "\1\1"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to make sure that you are using qualified document references rther than switching the active document to the file you wish to process .  SO show us some of your code so we can see your coding style.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the document to work on, not just a 'selection' that could only refer to whatever document is visible. For example, the following code tells Word to open a specific document and process only that document, even if it ceases to be visible:

```
Sub Lengthen()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim wdDoc As Document
Set wdDoc = Documents.Open("Path & Filename")
With wdDoc.Range.Find
  .ClearFormatting
  .Replacement.ClearFormatting
  .Text = "([aeiou" & ChrW(618) & ChrW(650) & "]):"
  .Replacement.Text = "\1\1"
  .Forward = True
  .Wrap = wdFindContinue
  .Format = False
  .MatchWildcards = True
  .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
End Sub
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Since I can't hard-code the file name in the macro and want it to be "whatever file I call this from", is there a way to get the name of the document from which the macro is called?

Comment: `ThisDocument` is where the code is running.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Activedocument to get the name of the current document.

```
Sub FindDoc()
    Dim myDoc As Document
    Set myDoc = ActiveDocument
    MsgBox myDoc.Name
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can decouple activities from the selection by using the duplicate property of the Word.Range.  A small adjustment to your code will allow the Find and Replace to take place without affecting you current selection (although the text in the selection may change due to the find/replace)

```
Sub Lengthen()
'
' Lengthen Macro
'
    Dim myRange As Word.Range
    Set myRange = Selection.Range.Duplicate
    
    With myRange.Find
    
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = "([aeiou" & ChrW(618) & ChrW(650) & "]):"
        .Replacement.Text = "\1\1"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        
    End With
    
End Sub
```

If you need to do additional things in the document with the selection then you can qualify the document from the selection range using

```
Dim myDoc As Word.Document
Set myDoc = Selection.Document
```